# mysql find/replace string in fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a few varchar fields named like this:

image_fullres | image_highres | image_mediumres | image_lowres | image_thumbnail

I currently have the same value for each of these fields(differing by row), so **image_fullres** has the same path as **image_lowres** and so on.

an example value for these paths would be `http://mysite.com/images/image1.jpg`

I would like to have each of these fields to contain a different and appropriate path name, so:

- **image_fullres** has value of **http://mysite.com/images/fullres/image1.jpg**
- **image_highres** has value of **http://mysite.com/images/highres/image1.jpg**
- **image_mediumres** has value of **http://mysite.com/images/mediumres/image1.jpg**

and so on...

Since all of my data is already in the database with duplicate paths by row, what SQL can I execute that would change the value of each field's data to an appropriate path?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Example:

```
UPDATE table 
SET image_fullres = REPLACE(image_fullres, 'http://mysite.com/images/', 'http://mysite.com/images/fullres/')
```

This will update the image_fullres column for all rows in your table. You can do one such statement for each column, or combine them into one:

```
UPDATE table 
SET
image_fullres = REPLACE(image_fullres, 'http://mysite.com/images/', 'http://mysite.com/images/fullres/'),
image_highres = REPLACE(image_highres, 'http://mysite.com/images/', 'http://mysite.com/images/highres/'),
...
...
```